# Is it reliable and documented how PYTHONPATH populates the sys.path?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-import

On my machine, the values from `PYTHONPATH` appear to get inserted in `sys.path`:

- beginning at index 1
- order preserved
- de-duplicated

For example, with `PYTHONPATH=/spam:/eggs:/spam` and then checking in `python -m site`, I get a result like:

```
sys.path = [
    something,
    '/spam',
    '/eggs',
    more,
    stuff,
    after
]
```

It seems to be the same behaviour on Python 2 and Python 3.  The question is, how much of this handling of `PYTHONPATH` is documented / reliable, and what if any might be different on other platforms?  Is this baked into the interpreter, or is handled by `site.py` and/or in danger of being "tweaked" by sysadmins?

I can't see it explained in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), it just says `sys.path` is "augmented" (and, contrary to the documentation, non-existent directories do not appear to be silently ignored).

Comment: Non-existent directories are silently ignored *when importing.*

Comment: @kindall Yes, I figured they meant that (since the underlying filesystem can change during runtime).  But the wording is ambiguous.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is just no, it's not documented.

Comment: If you want the path to be consistent, there is nothing at all stopping you from setting it up however you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go down the list.

---

> - beginning at index 1

That's reliable. As stated in the [PYTHONPATH docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH),

> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally
>   begins with prefix/lib/pythonversion (see PYTHONHOME above). It is
>   always appended to PYTHONPATH.
>
> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front
>   of PYTHONPATH as described above under Interface options. The search
>   path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the variable
>   sys.path.

One directory is inserted before PYTHONPATH, which may be the current directory, the script directory, or some other directory depending on how you ran Python. Other directories are appended. The [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) will also add some modules to `sys.path`, but `site` appends too:

> Importing this module will append site-specific paths to the module search path and add a few builtins...

---

> - order preserved

I don't think this is explicitly documented anywhere, but search path order is important, and changing it is a backward compatibility break I don't think they would make lightly.

---

> - de-duplicated

That's an undocumented effect of the `site` module. It won't happen if you run Python with the `-S` flag that disables `site`. You can see the code in [`site.removeduppaths`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/site.py#L115)