# What is the additional directory in front of PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, python-import

In the [documentation for the PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), what exactly is this **additional directory**?

> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front of PYTHONPATH as described above under [Interface options](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#using-on-interface-options).

Comment: It says "as described above under [Interface options](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#using-on-interface-options)". Did you read the link?

Comment: @user2357112 To be fair, I just read that linked section, and it's also not clear to me what exactly this sentence is referring to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it reliable and documented how PYTHONPATH populates the sys.path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020495/is-it-reliable-and-documented-how-pythonpath-populates-the-sys-path)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#using-on-interface-options) in your quote.

> `-c <command>`
> ...If this option is given, ...the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path
>
> `-m <module-name>`
> ...If this option is given, ...As with the -c option, the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.
>
> `-`
> ...If this option is given, ...the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.
>
> `<script>`
> ...If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of sys.path...
> If the script name refers to a directory or zipfile, the script name is added to the start of sys.path...
>
> If no interface option is given, -i is implied, sys.argv[0] is an empty string ("") and the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.